# Linq - OrderBy the minimum value of two columns using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have an entity set that contains two DateTime properties. I want to order the set by the minimum value of the two properties. How can I do this with a lambda expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myEntitySet.OrderBy(e => e.DateA < e.DateB ? e.DateA : e.DateB);
```